# A variable in a Python conditional statement

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

A variable in a Python conditional statement.

Hello my friends
How can I define a condition with a variable in Python?

One of my algorithms will have 1000 bets. I want to throw an expression in the loop and the indices of the variables will change.

Comment: This is very vague; can you clarify your intent and add examples please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:=` as follow

```py
if (a := 1) == 1:
    print("True") # True

print(a) # 1
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry, it doesn't work, maybe I can't use it

Comment: @MohammadSadati, the [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (also called the _walrus operator_) is new in Python 3.8. What version do you use?

Comment: @dirin, FYI: an answer is more useful when adding some context (i.e. a link to the official documentation, as in my previous comment). You might want to explain why/how this does work, and if there any limitiations (such as a minimum Python version).

Comment: You are right. I use version 3.10

Comment: When I run the above code, my initial list still remains empty
list1=[]
b0= 0
b5= 5
b2=10
b3=12


for i in range(1,4):
    if (b:=i)>5: b0 +=2
print(b0)

For example, in this code, I expect the value of b0 to change, but it doesn't

Comment: @MohammadSadati, there is no `list1` in this answer. Please edit your question to clarify what you try to achieve, so the question is more clear and anyone can help answering it. Comments are not meant for follow-up questions like this.